# SQL Table Schema question

Tags: mysql, schema

I recently started appending the name of my table to all my columns in a table. So say I had these tables:

```
Companies:

Id | Name | Logo | Info


Companies Employees:

Company Id | Employees Id


Employees:

Id | Name
```

I would change the column names to:

```
Companies:

Company Id | Company Name | Company Logo | Company Info


Companies Employees:

Company Id | Employee Id


Employees:

Employee Id | Employee Name
```

Which allows me to use queries like `` SELECT * FROM `Companies` NATURAL JOIN `Companies Employees` NATURAL JOIN `Employees` `` without worry about renaming the `Id` and `Name` columns since I'm guaranteed there won't be columns with the same name is my `Companies` and `Employees` table. But I'm wondering if this is good schema design practice? I don't want to make a habit of it if there are good reasons against it, but I haven't been able to think of any other than a lot of redundant retyping the table name.

Comment: You can always reference columns by table aliases. However, if you're using `NATURAL JOIN`s, uniqueness is probably the way to go. I'd prefer to avoid spaces in my column names, but others might disagree on the necessity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joining tables without explicitly naming key columns works great with simple queries but tends to mess things up when you need to join three or more tables. I've found that problem every time I've tried to replace the `ON` clause with `USING()`.

E.g.: Let's say you want to obtain a sales report by city. You can consider the office city or the customer city. Both tables `customer` and `office` will have a `city_id` foreign key pointing to the `city` table but NATURAL JOIN cannot know which one you want to join on as soon as you query customers and offices in the same query.

In any case, using unique columns by itself is a good trick. It saves you from a lot of `SELECT foo.id AS foo_id...`.

Answer (score 1):

Two bad practices in one post.

1. Don't do it like that, it doesn't add neither to functionality, nor to readability. The only place you need to use the table name prefix is on the relationship table.

2. Don't use `NATURAL JOIN`'s

Comment: What should I use instead of `NATURAL JOIN` in this case?

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` or `INNER JOIN`. The second one would be the most appropriate to your case.

Answer (score 0):

why so hard to write `Companies.Name` or `Employee.Id`? I think it is waste of your time.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the name of the table to each column can be helpful in a few different situations-

- When you join 2 tables which would otherwise share several column names, it saves you from having to assign aliases to distinguish columns
- I tend to use database column names throughout my web applications to maintain consistency; I'll keep the column name in form fields, variables, etc which deal with the same data item.  In larger databases with over 100 tables, it helps me stay organized having the table name prefixed on the variable.  Not to mention, it can help someone who's new to a project if they can see which table a variable came from.
- When you're specifying a foreign key in a table, it helps immensely if you have a naming convention which specifies which table the key belongs to.  There's nothing worse than seeing a foreign key and not knowing which table it is supposed to belong to.

The only downside to prefixing columns with the table name is that it can get a bit lengthy.

Comment: 1. You will have to use both the table name and column name if you don't use aliases. You will use `Company.Company_Id`, you see the redundancy? 2. If you tend to keep the column names throughout the application's variables, then obviously you are not working with objects. Though, it's fine to use them in forms. 3. That's definitely the place where this table name prefixes should be used. On other occasions it seems redundant and unnecessary.

Comment: I prefix foreign keys with `join_`, so `Company.Company_Id` is never needed.  Since fields from different tables rarely overlap, full specification of the field is almost never needed